# calling operator<< in gdb

Tags: c++, gdb, stream-operators

How do you call `operator<<(std::ostream &os, const ClassX &x)` from inside gdb ?

In other words, how do you print an object in gdb ?

`call std::cout<<x` or `call operator<<(std::cout, x)` don't seems to work for me!

Any ideas?

Comment: I type in the command `print` to print variables and objects.

Comment: I am working with a class in which the operator<< does a lot so the information is readable, so it's a bit annoying to use print and have raw data.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The only way I found was this:

```
call 'operator<<(std::ostream&, myclass&)'(mycout, c)
```

Since `std::cout` wasn't visible to gdb for some reason, I had to resort to creating my own like this:

```
std::ostream mycout(std::cout.rdbuf());
```

You haven't stated any reasons for wanting to do this but won't `print yourvariable` be easier?

If this is an absolute must you could have a `Print` method in your class and call that from `operator<<` and then call the `Print` method on your object from gdb.

Do take note that stdout is probably buffered in gdb so you won't be seeing any output unless you redirect it somehow.

See [this](http://sourceware.org/ml/gdb/2006-08/msg00237.html) discussion from gdb's mailing archive regarding this issue.

Answer (score 7):

You can also define a function like:

```
define printType
call operator<<(std::ostream&, const $arg0 &)(std::cerr, $arg1)
end
```

And use it like:

> printType ClassX objectOfClassX

Comment: On Ubuntu 18.04, GDB 8.1.0, you don't need to pass the class type explicitly, as C++ can deduce template types from arguments. However for some reason `cout` didn't work, only `cerr`, likely due to a missing flush. But I can't flush as explained at:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832964/calling-operator-in-gdb#comment102981298_48601472

Answer (score 3):

For me `call operator<<` ran without error, but didn't print.  Turns out I needed a call to `flush`.  Here's a useful function you can put in `.gdbinit`:

```
define str
    call (void)operator<<(std::cout, $arg0)
    call (void)std::cout.flush()
    printf "\n"
end
```

Comment: How would you call this from the gdb console?

Comment: Call it with no parentheses, like so: `str my_variable`

Comment: On Ubuntu 18.04, GDB 8.1.0 this fails with `Couldn't find method std::ostream::flush` and this minimal example: https://gist.github.com/cirosantilli/d438e38f05a92422f909c0571a2dac16 `cerr` worked though without flush for some reason. `call fflush(0)` did work though, but not sure how sane that is.

Comment: It could be that nothing in your program calls std::flush and so that function is not linked into your executable.  You do use std::endl, which does a flush, but perhaps libstdc++ does this flush directly rather than via std::flush.  Try adding an explicit std::flush into your example.  Of course, if fflush(0) works, then you are already set.

Answer (score 2):

I have the following in my `.gdbinit`. The previous answers here did not work for me when the `operator<<` is a template or required a lot of typing to get the types right. This approach searches the symbol table to find the correct `operator<<`. This only works if the operators have been instantiated explicitly.

```py
python
import gdb
import re
class LexicalCast(gdb.Command):
    def __init__(self):
        super(LexicalCast, self).__init__("lexical_cast", gdb.COMMAND_DATA)

    def matches(self, symbol, type, exact=True):
        params = symbol.find('('), symbol.find(')')
        if -1 in params: return False
        params = symbol[params[0]+1 : params[1]]
        if re.match("^%s, %s( const)?&?$"%(re.escape("std::ostream&"), re.escape(type)), params): return True
        if not exact and re.match("^%s, .*::%s( const)?&?$"%(re.escape("std::ostream&"), re.escape(type)), params): return True
        return False

    def invoke(self, arg, from_tty):
        value = gdb.parse_and_eval(arg)
        type = str(value.type.strip_typedefs().unqualified())
        # isn't unqualified() supposed to do that already?
        if type.startswith("const "): type = type[6:]
        if type.startswith("struct "): type = type[7:]
        if type.endswith(" &"): type = type[:-2]
        # there's probably a better way to browse the list of symbols ...
        shift_operators = gdb.execute("info functions operator<<", False, True).split('\n')  
        matching_operators = [ op for op in shift_operators if self.matches(op, type)]
        if not matching_operators:
            gdb.write("No operator<<(std::ostream&, const %s&) found in the symbols. Trying to find a match with additional namespace qualifiers.\n"%(type,))
            matching_operators = [ op for op in shift_operators if self.matches(op, type, False)]

        if not matching_operators:
            gdb.write("No operator<<(std::ostream&, const .*::%s&) found in the symbols. Did you forget to explicitly instantiate your operator?\n"%(type,))     
        else:
            if len(matching_operators) > 1:
                gdb.write("Found multiple operator<< matching this expression; trying to call each one of them...\n")                          
            for op in matching_operators:
                try:                     
                    op = op.split('  ', 1)[1][:-4] if op.endswith("@plt") else op.split(':', 1)[1].split('&', 1)[1].strip()[:-1]
                    gdb.execute("call (void)'%s'((std::cout), (%s))"%(op, arg))      
                    gdb.execute("call (void)std::cout.put('\\n')")
                    gdb.execute("call (void)std::cout.flush()")
                    break
                except Exception as e:
                    gdb.write("Could not invoke %s: %s\n"%(op, e))

LexicalCast()
end
```

In GDB I use it like this:

```
(gdb) lex sector[0]
4: 1 ~ ([-3.00170 +/- 3.86e-6], [-1.73303 +/- 7.55e-8])
(gdb) lex 123
No operator<<(std::ostream&, const int&) found in the symbols. Did you explicitly instantiate that operator?
```

This is mostly a hack of course that likely breaks if you have changed how GDB prints `info functions`, but it works well for my purposes.