# Printing C++ class objects with GDB

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb

Is there some "default function" to print an object like a string on the GDB when we are debugging C++ applications? Something like: toString();

Or my class have to implement something like that?

Comment: This is probably the closest you're going to get.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549930/c-equivalent-of-java-tostring

Comment: have you checked this? http://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/STLSupport

Comment: You have to implement it. You can usually drill into the members in a debugger and see what you're looking for, however.

Comment: The best thing to do is [write a Python pretty printer](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Writing-a-Pretty_002dPrinter.html#Writing-a-Pretty_002dPrinter) for GDB to use when printing your own types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could always have printed `std::string` (or anything else for that matter) using `print` command. However, struggling with C++ template container internals might not be pleasant. In the recent versions of toolchains (GDB + Python + Pretty Printers that are usually installed together as part of the development packages on most user-friendly Linux distros), those are automatically recognized and printed (pretty!). For example:

```
$ cat test.cpp 
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string s = "Hello, World!";
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
}

$ g++ -Wall -ggdb -o test ./test.cpp 
$ gdb ./test 

(gdb) break main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x400ae5: file ./test.cpp, line 6.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /tmp/test 

Breakpoint 1, main () at ./test.cpp:6
6       std::string s = "Hello, World!";
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install glibc-2.16-28.fc18.x86_64 libgcc-4.7.2-8.fc18.x86_64 libstdc++-4.7.2-8.fc18.x86_64
(gdb) next
7       std::cout << s << std::endl;
(gdb) p s
$1 = "Hello, World!"
(gdb)
```

As @111111 pointed out, check out http://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/STLSupport for instructions on how to get this installed yourself.

Comment: A recent GDB isn't enough, that output is done by pretty printers included with recent versions of GCC, using the embedded Python interpreter in recent versions of GDB

Comment: @JonathanWakely: Correct. It is probably more appropriate to say toolchain than gdb... This stuff is usually installed by default with dev packages in most of the "user friendly" distros.

Answer (score 2):

You can [call any member functions](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Calling.html) from Standard Library or your own data type during debug session. This is sometimes the easiest way to output object state in gdb. For `std::string` you could call it's `c_str()` member which returns `const char*`:

```
(gdb) p str.c_str()
$1 = "Hello, World!"
```

Though this will work only for debugging live process, but not for core dump debugging.

Answer (score 1):

gdb has a built-in `print` command that you can call in gdb on any variable or expression to see its value. You should look at the gdb documentation for details. You can find the full manual [here](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/) and a decent intro guide can be found [here](http://beej.us/guide/bggdb/)

Answer (score 1):

**Define `operator<<` and call it from GDB**

[C++ equivalent of Java's toString?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549930/c-equivalent-of-javas-tostring) was mentioned in the comments, and `operator<<` is the most common way of defining a to string method on a class.

This is likely the sanest approach because the resulting string method will be part of the codebase itself, and so:

- it is less to stop compiling (one would hope!)
- it is readily available without any GDB setup
- it can be called from C++ itself when needed

Unfortunately I haven't found a completely sane way of calling `operator<<` from GDB, what a mess: [calling operator<< in gdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832964/calling-operator-in-gdb)

This has worked on my hello world test:

```
(gdb) call (void)operator<<(std::cerr, my_class)
MyClass: i = 0(gdb)
```

There is no newline at the end, but I can live with that.

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

struct MyClass {
    int i;
    MyClass() { i = 0; }
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &oss, const MyClass &my_class) {
    return oss << "MyClass: i = " << my_class.i;
}

int main() {
    MyClass my_class;
    std::cout << my_class << std::endl;
}
```

Compiled with:

```
g++ -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -o main.out main.cpp
```

Tested in GDB 8.1.0, Ubuntu 18.04.